# Change Group Id in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.0,  and i am trying to change the group Id for my custom module for Registration.

I tried with

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />`
```

and

```
$customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getParam('group_id'));
```

but its not work

Comment: The instance of `$customer`?

Comment: Please post your code. Using `$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');` have u load customer first, then changed then saved?

Answer (score 0):

I have face **same issue at few days.** and  have resolve this by Myself.

The main issue in [Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L92) class. Here magento statically set `group_id` to default  `group id` of that store.

**That reason yours group_id does not and it taken default group id .**

I have post  that [magento2 issue #2650](http://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2650) as bug.

**But @Vinai and other masters does  not agree with me**  that this is a bug at magento.They have raised the flag for if we allow the ***customer to change customer group id from frontend that can be a security leak  and not good  for the health of business***

but till now i am not accept this logic :)

If you want to change group id then you need to change below changes at code

### Solution

You need enable group_id for customer register page by run this query:

```
INSERT INTOcustomer_form_attribute(form_code,attribute_id) VALUES ('customer_account_create', '10');
```

1. don't execute [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93) when **_group_id_** is enable for  registration form
2. execute  [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93)  when  **_group_id_** is  **not enable for  registration form**
3. execute  [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93)  when  **_group_id_** is  **enable for  registration form *  but group id **does not selected** from form

So. my suggestion change `if ($isGroupIdEmpty) {`

to

```
if (!$isGroupIdAllow || ($isGroupIdAllow &&(is_null($customerDataObject->getGroupId()))) ) {
            $customerDataObject->setGroupId(
                $this->customerGroupManagement->getDefaultGroup($store->getId())->getId()
            );
        }
```

Also for use developer perspective change variable name
[$isGroupIdEmpty](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L83)

to

`isGroupIdAllow`